# Is there a career mode in Forza 6 Apex? If so, how to start it?

Tags: forza-motorsport-6

Just downloaded Forza 6 Apex (Windows 10), did the introduction races. What I always enjoyed about these games is starting with almost nothing and progressively earn more money, buy better cars, and upgrading them of course.

I don't see that mode in this game. Am I overlooking something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Forza Motorsport 6: Apex* is a slimmed down version of the larger Forza Motorsport 6 which had a career mode.

***Unfortunately this game, being a slimmer version, does not have what you are expecting.***

The only thing that you can find a little similar to the career mode are the 12 different events on a kind of a racing calendar (first menu button with recommended events)

More information about the game and menu:

https://gamingbolt.com/forza-motorsport-6-apex-wiki
https://forums.forzamotorsport.net/turn10_postsm469206_Forza-Motorsport-6--Apex-quick-facts-and-FAQ.aspx#post_469206